# Ubuntu installation - partitions not found

Tags: installation, data-recovery

I replaced Windows with Ubuntu, but when I log in into Ubuntu, the drives (partitions) are not to be seen, and there are important files on my drives.

Windows was installed in `C:\`. I need the other drives so that I could recover the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you set during installation **Replace Windows with Ubuntu**, than all the files on your system were *deleted*.

You can try use some data recovery [programs](https://www.google.sk/search?hl=sk&source=hp&q=files+recovery+ubuntu&btnG=H%C4%BEada%C5%A5+v+Google&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) but you *may not succeed to recover* all of your data.